# What is the canonical alternative to calling a React hook inside of a loop?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand [*that*](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) you aren't supposed to call React hooks inside of a loop. However, I am not sure what the canonical alternative would be, if there even is one.

As an example, consider the following ([CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-new?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000062e670je7ghck%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000022e67dxfawaah%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000032e67i4eqtnm3%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000052e67bddn6yep%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpt2h53000022e67dxfawaah%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000012e6752ur7im0%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A11%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A12%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A11%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A12%257D%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000022e67dxfawaah%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000012e6752ur7im0%2522%257D%252C%2522clpt2h53000052e67bddn6yep%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000042e67wzif4i5u%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000052e67bddn6yep%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000042e67wzif4i5u%2522%257D%252C%2522clpt2h53000032e67i4eqtnm3%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpt2h53000032e67i4eqtnm3%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)):

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default () => {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
  const users = [];

  for (let userId of userIds) {
    const user = useFetchUser(userId);

    users.push(user);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <div>
          {user.id} - {user.name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const useFetchUser = (id) => {
  const nameMap = {
    1: "Alice",
    2: "Bob",
    3: "Carol",
  };
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const name = nameMap[id];

      setUser({
        id,
        name,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }, [id]);

  return user;
};
```

This isn't advisable (but does *work*) because it involves calling a hook (`useFetchUser`) inside of a loop. What would be the canonical way of approaching this situation?

---

The first thought that comes to my mind would be to have a `useFetchUsers` (plural) hook instead that fetches all of the users instead of just one. However, creating such a hook that uses `useFetchUser` like so doesn't work.

```
const useFetchUsers = (ids) => {
  const users = [];

  for (let id of ids) {
    const user = useFetchUser(id);

    users.push(user);
  }

  return users;
};
```

Or at least it still gives the following lint error:

```
React Hook "useFetchUser" may be executed more than once. Possibly because it is called in a loop. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render. (react-hooks/rules-of-hooks)eslint
```

So maybe the solution would be to ditch `useFetchUser` and write your own `useFetchUsers` hook with new logic that replaces `useFetchUser`. In this simple example, that'd probably be fine. However, in various more complex real world scenarios it is often impractical to ditch whatever the equivalent of `useFetchUser` is.

Comment: In this case, your `useFetcher` is not a hook, because it's using neither useState nor useEffect - it's just a plan function! Most React request libraries (that manage state for you) allow you to pass a custom fetch function, where you can make one or multiple requests if you want.

Comment: @moonwave99 My mistake. I just updated the question to update `useFetchUser` such that it is a proper React hook. Suppose for the purpose of this question that we are in a situation where we can't pass a custom fetch function.

Comment: I suppose the example works because the userIds array doesn't change across different renders. Because the order of calling hooks is important for React, so I guess if userIds is dynamic (like it will grow over time and passed as a prop), it might throw an error when `userIds` changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change how you compose your components. Make a `User` component that calls the hook:

```
const App = () => {
  const userIds = [1, 2, 3];

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Users</h1>
      {userIds.map((userId) => <User userId={userId} key={userId} />)}
    </div>
  );
}

const User = (props) => {
  const userId = props.userId;
  // Returns `undefined` until the user is loaded
  const user = useFetchUser(userId);

  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div>{user.name}</div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What if I want to cache the data in the parent element? Or is that just a bad idea in general?

Comment: That makes sense as a possible solution, but it doesn't feel to me like it is likely to be the best solution. I can imagine situations where you prefer to do all of the data fetching in the parent component.

Comment: If you want to do it in the parent then just change your hook to return the promise.all: `const users = useFetchUsers(userIds)`. Then just pass the entire loaded user object into the `User` component

Comment: @MatthewHerbst That sounds like it'd involve calling `useFetchUser` in some sort of loop inside of `useFetchUsers`, and hooks aren't supposed to be called in a loop.

Comment: Why does the inner call need to be a hook? `const useFetchUsers = (userIds) => useMemo(() => Promise.all(userIds.map(userId => fetch("/user", { method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify({ userId })}).then(res => res.json())), [userIds])`;

Comment: In this made up example, it probably is easy enough to ditch `useFetchUser` and write some logic for that inner call to fetch an individual user. However, I can imagine real world scenarios where it is most pragmatic to use whatever corresponds to `useFetchUser`, and so I'm supposing in this question that we do want to keep `useFetchUser`.

Comment: For example, Relay's https://relay.dev/docs/api-reference/use-query-loader/

Comment: @AdamZerner the only way to properly call a hook in a loop is to render a bunch of individual components that each call the hook. So either follow that pattern or modify your hook logic. IMHO, good practice is to keep as much business logic out of React (or whatever rendering framework you use) as possible. Will help you write more maintainable and stateless/minimally stateful components.